# Como pesquisar nas minhas próprias respostas?

Tags: suporte

Tenho, por exemplo, 10 páginas de perguntas.

Quero pesquisar somente nelas, um certo conteúdo no título ou no conteúdo da questão. Tem essa possibilidade ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isto:

[image: Resultado da busca avançada com critérios]

Pode ser feito pelo perfil:

[image: Topbar com o box de pesquisa com o número do usuário]

Comment: Exatamente ! Eu achei que houvesse algo no perfil, e nunca tinha me atentado a essa "pesquisa avançada". Que vergonha ! :D

Comment: `user:me` também funciona ;)